# Return subset of variable-length array

Tags: solidity, contract-design, assembly

How does one return the first x elements of an array of addresses?

I'm pretty sure this can be done in assembly but could not find the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would lobby for a more idiomatic & cautious approach, returning one row at a time. That will give you a fixed cost *per transaction* at any scale. As a general rule of thumb, any process that iterates *n times* has a hard limit at the block gasLimit which varies over time.

```
address[] public myAddresses;

function getAddressCount() public view returns(uint count) {
  return myAddresses.length;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That makes sense. My intent is to implement a function with a fixed cost per transaction (say, returning 100 elements at a time starting from a certain index, to save calls by the front-end). My understanding is that this can be accomplished without iteration in assembly, by returning `array(startPosition, length)` or something like that, and it just returns that chunk in storage. Will add when I find the reference.

Comment: Whether that's the right approach is another question. I am planning for cases where there are potentially hundreds of thousands of rows that have to be queried, which would be unwieldy to retrieve in a single call and impractical to do one at a time (although maybe that's still be the best solution, I don't know the overhead costs of making a call).

Comment: How would you deal with a big list of items? if you have, for example, a list of 5k elements to iterate I would think that a pagination would be the easiest approach, I don't think the single item approach is the best one, right ?

Comment: The bigger the list, the more appropriate is the single item approach. Returning the entire list is an O(n) operation and pagination is unwanted complexity in the contract. Use the contract as the system of record, the source of truth, and consider a caching server to gather the verifiable facts and present them in various convenient forms.